# my java "word count from file" program is inaccurate

Tags: java

I am using a fairly basic logic for counting words from a ".txt" file in my java program & i do get accurate count for a single line in the file, but for some reason the count falls short 1 count every time a new line is encountered in the file...? any help as to where my logic falls short would be great help !!

**my code**

```
        int count = 1; // any alternative for this ... ?

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ("practice.txt");

        int c,f=0;          

        while((c = fis.read()) != -1)
        {
            if ( c != ' ')
            {
                f = 1;
            }
            if(f == 1 && c == ' ')
            {
                count++;
                f=0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

Just to give a perspective:
now if when i compile & run this on a text file with a single line like: **"Welcome to java"**

the result is:

```
  3 // accurate
```

but if the file gets a new line i.e

**"Welcome to Java**

**this is line 2"** .............. I get:

```
 6
```

now as the lines increase the result decreases 1 for each line...!?

(I am trying to be absolutely basic so am not using the tokenizer / split or any other built-in method for this)

Comment: You don't seem to have any code that would understand and account for a line break char. I see only space handled here.

Comment: Since these are not answers, but merely suggestions, I'm leaving them in a comment. `1`: Consider reading more than 1 character at a time. `2`: Consider using a Pattern/Regular Expression and using the '\s' whitespace delimiter to match ALL whitespace

Answer (score 1):

The newlines are not space characters so when you have this

```
"Welcome to Java

this is line 2"
```

It's being read by your program as

`"Welcome to Java\nthis is line 2"`

So you can add the newline escape sequence `\n` to your program to handle that

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking for spaces.  You need to check for new lines (`\n`) also.  Thus you are counting Java and this as one word.

If you test your program like this, you can modify the test data pretty easily to check other cases.  Then you can alter to read in the file.

And you may want to modify your code to check for tab (`\t`) characters since they may also separate words.

```
        int count = 1; // any alternative for this ... ?

        String str = "Welcome to Java\nThis is a test";

        int f = 0;

        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (c != ' ' && c != '\n') {
                f = 1;
            }
            if (f == 1 && (c == ' ' || c == '\n')) {

                count++;
                f = 0;

            }

        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

The reason it worked for count = 1, is that when the for loop is done cycling thru the questions, the last word is not counted because the process abruptly ends.  The same thing with your reading from a file.  To see this set count = 0 run it and see.  It will be 6. Then put a space at the end of the string and the count will be 7.  So you need to put something like this when you end up reading in characters.

```
if (f == 1) {
   count++;
}
```

Then you can initialize count = 0;

Comment: i tried the logic it worked great !! but the only problem was i still have to set my counters to 1 instead of 0. it seems the comment near the initialization of the counter at the declaration of "count" went un-noticed any advice on that glitch..??